# Enum retorna null do banco

Tags: java, design-pattern, padrão-dao, resultset, enums

Olá, estou implementando um **DAO** e fazendo alguns testes, estou tendo alguns problemas nos enums. Ao rodar a classe teste o enum **Tamanho** retorna null, mas no banco tenho registros preenchidos corretamente.

Classe de teste:

```
package br.com.caelum.jdbc.teste;

import java.util.List;

import br.com.caelum.jdbc.dao.ContatoDAO;
import br.com.caelum.jdbc.modelo.Contato;
public class TestaLista {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ContatoDAO contatoDAO = new ContatoDAO();

        List<Contato> contatos = contatoDAO.getLista();

        for (Contato contato : contatos) {
              System.out.println("Nome: " + contato.getNome());
              System.out.println("Email: " + contato.getEmail());
              System.out.println("Endereço: " + contato.getEndereco());
              System.out.println("Data de Nascimento: " + contato.getDataNascimento() + "\n");
              System.out.println("Tamanho: " + contato.getTamanho());
          }
    }
}
```

Essa é a classe Contato, meu objeto principal e tem uma tabela equivalente no banco:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;

import br.com.caelum.jdbc.dao.Tamanho;

public class Contato {

    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private String endereco;
    private LocalDate dataNascimento;
    private LocalTime horaAgendada;
    private Tamanho tamanho;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public LocalDate getDataNascimento() {
        return dataNascimento;
    }

    public void setDataNascimento(LocalDate dataNascimento) {
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }

    public LocalTime getHoraAgendada() {
        return horaAgendada;
    }

    public void setHoraAgendada(LocalTime horaAgendada) {
        this.horaAgendada = horaAgendada;
    }

    public Tamanho getTamanho() {
        return tamanho;
    }
    public void setTamanho(Tamanho tamanho) {
        this.tamanho = tamanho;
    }
}
```

Meu Enum Tamanho (só estou testando os retornos do banco, então fiz um enum qualquer só pra testar). Adicionei metodo toTamanho para tentar resolver, pq sem ele eu nem conseguia retorno, apenas o erro abaixo:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null
>       at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
>       at br.com.caelum.jdbc.dao.Tamanho.valueOf(Tamanho.java:1)
>       at br.com.caelum.jdbc.dao.ContatoDAO.getLista(ContatoDAO.java:61)
>       at br.com.caelum.jdbc.teste.TestaLista.main(TestaLista.java:17)

```
    package br.com.caelum.jdbc.dao;

public enum Tamanho {

    xSmall("x-small"),
    small("small"),
    medium("medium"), 
    large("large"),
    xLarge("x-large'");

    private String tamanho;

    Tamanho(final String tamanho){
        this.tamanho = tamanho;
    }

    public String getTamanho() {
        return tamanho;
    }

    public void setTamanho(String tamanho) {
        this.tamanho= tamanho;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return tamanho;
    }



    public static Tamanho toTamanho(String value) {
        for (Tamanho tamanho : values()) {
            if (tamanho.equals(value)) {
                return tamanho;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

E esse é o resultado obtido após a execução da classe **TestaLista**:

```
Nome: teste
Email: teste@teste.com
Endereço: Rua teste testeira
Data de Nascimento: 2018-02-21

Tamanho: null
Nome: teste
Email: teste@teste.com
Endereço: Rua teste testeira
Data de Nascimento: 2018-02-21

Tamanho: null
Nome: teste
Email: teste@teste.com
Endereço: Rua teste testeira
Data de Nascimento: 2018-02-21

Tamanho: null
Nome: teste
Email: teste@teste.com
Endereço: Rua teste testeira
Data de Nascimento: 2018-02-23

Tamanho: null
Nome: teste
Email: teste@teste.com
Endereço: Rua teste testeira
Data de Nascimento: 2018-02-23

Tamanho: null
```

um print da tabela no banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom, em resumo eu quero acessar o enum no banco. Mesmo que seja de outra forma. Vlw a todos desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar isso também:

```
// método getLista()

...

contato.setTamanho(Tamanho.valueOf(objetoResultSet.getString("size")));
```

Conforme [descrito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/278955/enum-retorna-null-do-banco#comment569971_278969) como na sua tabela possui valor null em alguns registros isso ocasiona o erro NullPointerException ao atribuir em seu enum.

Uma forma de contornar esse erro poderia buscar apenas registros com size diferente de nulo.

- `select * from contatos where size != null`

Comment: Então, eu tentei com valueOf mas recebi esse erro:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236) at br.com.caelum.jdbc.dao.Tamanho.valueOf(Tamanho.java:1) at br.com.caelum.jdbc.dao.ContatoDAO.getLista(ContatoDAO.java:61) at br.com.caelum.jdbc.teste.TestaLista.main(TestaLista.java:17)
|


O código do getLista é este:  https://pastebin.com/V2MZmfk7

Comment: Será que o erro é pq os nomes das minhas enums, tem "-" no banco e não tem na classe

Comment: Isso ocorre pois tem registros na coluna size como NULL, tente alterar o SELECT só para fins de testes: PreparedStatement stmt = this.connection.prepareStatement("select * from contatos where size != null");

Assim ele retorna apenas registro que contenha size

Comment: Opá, erá isso mesmo. É claro, eu nem percebi. No banco tinha um size = null. Outra coisa, um ENUM não pode ser null?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta espero ter ajudado =). "Outra coisa, um ENUM não pode ser null?" 

Bom depende, em meus projetos se utilizo Enums no meu BD é configurado como NOT NULL por estar trabalhando com constantes. Talvez você possa criar um valor padrão para caso seja NULL atribuir ao enum o valor padrão.

Comment: Ajudou sim, resolvi aqui, testei e ta funcionando.